# How does MCMC overcome the problem with high-dimensionality in rejection sampling?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, rejection-sampling

When using rejection sampling, in higher dimensions I understand the acceptance probability becomes very small and so many samples are discarded. How does MCMC overcome this?

Comment: One solution is to reduce the dimension at each iteration. This is the case with Gibbs sampling. Another one is to replace the bound in accept-reject (which grows with dimension) with a local value, as in Metropolis-Hastings, since it is always smaller.